# Integrate grep in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, grep, gzip

I am trying to learn bit of Python and my goal is to open `gzip file`, input the search query and then print it out, and eventually output results to the file.

```
import gzip
file = raw_input('Input Filepath: ')  # input file path
with gzip.open(file, 'rb') as f:  # opens gzip fil .gz
    file_content = f.read()  # reads the contents
    grep = raw_input('Enter Search: ')  # grep asks for output
print(file_content)  # prints it in console
```

I also tried with `print(file_content, grep)`, but it only returns the first find.

Comment: Please include an example of your file content as well as the expected output for a given grep value.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. `grep` is a command line utility. Are you trying to replicate its behavior here?

Comment: @ettanany I am trying to open gz file then output just information I enter in "search" I thought of using grep as thats how I knew /know best to get the results by just doing

Comment: if `file_content` is a string then you can use standard string functions - like `find()`. If you need something like grep then you need regular expressions and module `re`

Comment: File contents 
s3r324233e-2313314ss-Sf324sgthtj65u234 : ***:2016-12-05 18:54:48,529 INFO [w.v.w.p.smallbigfirmInterceptor].? http-bio-8090-exec-32 --- my_token:e2a61197-5bf3-4cdc-5555-8486f4c7ef61 their_token:sitetositerequest
So I am trying to print out the lines that contains "sitetositerequest"

Comment: @furas ill give a find() a go as well, but am not sure where to include that? as code

Comment: ie. `print( file_content.find('some_text') )` - it finds position of `'some_text'` in `file_content` but it need more work. And better find some Python tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `grep` utility will search for lines which match a given pattern.

To do that in python, you need to read the file line by line and then search each line for the string you want find:

```
import gzip

matched_lines = []
file = raw_input('Imput Filepath: ')
with gzip.open( file, 'rb') as f:
    grep = raw_input('Enter Search: ')
    for line in f: # read file line by line
        if grep in line: # search for string in each line
            matched_lines.append(line) # keep a list of matched lines

file_content = ''.join(matched_lines) # join the matched lines

print(file_content)
```

Comment: This worked as intended. It output the results I needed. How bad did I use my code beforehand? I read readlines() is bad to do so, because it captures info in memory.

Comment: @JJWatt. Yes, `readlines()` puts all the lines into a list first, so for a very large file it could use a lot of memory. However, sometimes you are forced to do things that way (e.g. if you wanted to sort all the lines).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you are trying to do something like

```
with gzip.open( file, 'rb') as f: #opens gzip fil .gz
    grep = raw_input('Enter Search: ')
    file_content = [line for line in f.readlines() if re.match(grep, line)]
```